# How to find out how much word used in a result/string with/without eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to find out how much a word used in laravel with eloquent. I'm not sure if it's possible with eloquent so if it's not how can i do this with php?

Example :

I'm getting results from below query :

```
    $posts = Posts::where('post_body', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')->get();
    $result = [];
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        // Logic here to push to result and how much searched word used in result and push to array
    }

    return $result;
```

so if i searched something like file name `12345.jpeg`, i want to know how much `12345.jpeg` used in `post_body`. check how much then push usage count with result to array.

More Example :

post body result : "this is 12345.jpeg and `<img src="12345.jpeg"/>`" => Return 2 time usage of 12345.jpeg in string

post body result : "this is 12345.jpeg and `<img src="12345.jpeg"/>` and more 12345.jpeg" => Return 3 time usage of 12345.jpeg in string

post body result : `happy world, happy life, Happy post` => Return how much `happy` is used in the result. which is 2 times since I've got 1 happy with `H`.

Comment: Your question is not well structured

Comment: Do you want to know the number or count of the search result?

Comment: @MarvinCollins ah, sorry forgot to add ` for used tag in example.

Comment: @MarvinCollins i want to know how much searched word used in a result , check example above, I've edited. if i searched `happy` and I've got ` happy world, happy life, happy post` as a result of record, i wan't to make sure how much happy used in 1 result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need.

```php
$posts = Posts::where('post_body', 'like', '%'.$name.'%')->get();

$posts->transform(function ($post) use ($name) {
  $post = (object) $post;
  $post->occurennces = substr_count($post->post_body, $name);
  return $post;
});

return $posts;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what i need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP's `substr_count` function.

Eg:

```
$s = "happy world, happy life, Happy post";
echo substr_count($s, "happy"); //yields 2.
```

> From documentation: **substr_count()** returns the number of times the needle substring occurs
> in the haystack string. Please note that needle is **case sensitive**.

Documentation link for reference:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php